# create boolean constraints in CPLEX

Tags: boolean, cplex, opl

I am using OPL in CPLEX 12.9

In my model, I have these two dvar boolean, `X[p][t]` and `Y[t]`. 
I want to write:

```
(Y[t] == 1) => (X[u][t] == 0);
```

But it should be also possible that

```
(Y[t] == 0) && (X[u][t] == 0);
```

But it doesn't works.
I hope someone have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you write

```
(Y[t] == 1) => (X[u][t] == 0);
```

the only scenario that is not possible is

```
(Y[t] == 1) && (X[u][t] == 1);
```

Comment: Yes the scenario only should be: (Y[t] == 1) => (X[u][t] == 0);  or (Y[t] == 0) && (X[u][t] == 0); but if I write (Y[t] == 1) => (X[u][t] == 0); the programm output for all the decision variable is "no value"

Comment: That means that for other reasons your model is not feasible. What you could do next is name your constraints and then you ll get some relaxations / conflicts

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Can you give me an example how I can name my constraints? If I named my constraints should I use the CP Solver then? Or can I solve with OPL

Comment: ct:x<=2; for instance. See specific documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_constraints_labeling.html

Comment: David Nehme and Alex Fleischer thank you so much for your help and advices! Your help solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The condition (y[t] == 1) => (x[u][t] == 1) can be expressed with the following linear constraint.

`y[t] + x[u][t] <= 1`

As long as y and x are binaries.  If y[1] is 1, then x[u][t] can only take on the value of 0.  If y[t] is 0, the x[u][t] can be either 0 or 1.